# Erro ao listar tabela direto do SQLite

Tags: java, android-studio

Galera é o seguinte: estou criando uma aplicação de controle de estoque, tenho uma tela da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico no botão "PRODUTO" era para ir para essa outra tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que quando clico clico no botão "PRODUTO" a aplicação trava, sendo que eu adicionei uma ListView para listar os produtos cadastrados, comentando o código da ListView ele funciona, mas a minha intenção é deixar listado os produto assim que a abrir a tela Produtos, segue a baixo o código:

Código da Classe Produtos:

```
public class Produtos extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

DBHelper bd;
ArrayList<Produto> listaProdutos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.produtos);

    bd = new DBHelper(this);
    ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ltvProdutos);
    listaProdutos = bd.getAllProdutos();
    ProdutoAdapter adapter = new ProdutoAdapter(this, listaProdutos);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Produtos.this, EditarProduto.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID", listaProdutos.get(i).getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Produtos.this, CadastroProduto.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    // User pressed the search button
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // User changed the text
    return false;
}

}
```

Código da classe banco:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 1;
private static final String NOME_BANCO = "CONTROLE_DE_ESTOQUE";
private static final String TABELA_PRODUTOS = "produtos";
private static final String ID = "_id";
private static final String DESCRICAO = "descricao";
private static final String CATEGORIA = "categoria";
private static final String UNIDADEMEDIDA = "unidadeMedida";
private static final String ESTOQUE_ATUAL = "estoqueAtual";
private static final String ESTOQUE_MINIMO = "estoqueMinimo";
private static final String VALOR_CUSTO = "valorCusto";
private static final String VALOR_VENDA = "valorVenda";
private static final String[] COLUNAS = {TABELA_PRODUTOS};

private static final String TABELA_FORNECEDORES = "fornecedores";
private static final String ID_FORNECEDOR = "_id";
private static final String RAZAO_SOCIAL = "razaoSocial";
private static final String CNPJ = "cnpj";
private static final String INSCRICAO_ESTADUAL = "inscricaoEstadual";
private static final String TELEFONE = "telefone";
private static final String ENDERECO = "endereco";
private static final String[] COLUNAS_FORNECEDOR = {TABELA_FORNECEDORES};


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO_BANCO);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String QUERY_USUARIO = "CREATE TABLE TABELA_USUARIOS (_ID integer primary key autoincrement, nomeUsuario TEXT, senha TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(QUERY_USUARIO);

    String QUERY_PRODUTO = "CREATE TABLE TABELA_PRODUTOS (_ID integer primary key autoincrement, descricao TEXT, categoria TEXT," +
            " unidadeMedida TEXT, valorCusto TEXT, valorVenda TEXT, estoqueAtual TEXT, estoqueMinimo TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(QUERY_PRODUTO);

    String QUERY_FORNECEDOR = "CREATE TABLE TABELA_FORNECEDORES (_ID integer primary key autoincrement, razaoSocial TEXT, cnpj TEXT," +
            " inscricaoEstadual TEXT, telefone TEXT, endereco TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(QUERY_FORNECEDOR);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABELA_USUARIOS;");
    onCreate(db);

}

public long CriarUsuario(String nomeUsuario, String senha) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("nomeusuario", nomeUsuario);
    cv.put("senha", senha);
    long result = db.insert("TABELA_USUARIOS", null, cv);
    return result;
}

public String ValidarUsuario(String nomeUsuario, String senha) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABELA_USUARIOS WHERE nomeUsuario=? AND senha=?", new String[]{nomeUsuario, senha});
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        return "OK";
    }
    return "ERRO";
}

public long CriarProduto(Produto produto) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DESCRICAO, produto.getDescricao());
    cv.put(CATEGORIA, produto.getCategoria());
    cv.put(UNIDADEMEDIDA, produto.getUnidadeMedida());
    cv.put(ESTOQUE_ATUAL, produto.getEstoqueAtual());
    cv.put(ESTOQUE_MINIMO, produto.getEstoqueMinimo());
    cv.put(VALOR_CUSTO, produto.getValorCusto());
    cv.put(VALOR_VENDA, produto.getValorVenda());

    long result = db.insert("TABELA_PRODUTOS", null, cv);
    return result;
}

public Produto getProduto(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABELA_PRODUTOS, // a. tabela
            COLUNAS, // b. colunas
            " id = ?", // c. colunas para comparar
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. parâmetros
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null); // h. limit
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Produto produto = cursorToProduto(cursor);
        return produto;
    }
}

private Produto cursorToProduto(Cursor cursor) {
    Produto produto = new Produto();
    produto.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    produto.setDescricao(cursor.getString(1));
    produto.setCategoria(cursor.getString(2));
    produto.setUnidadeMedida(cursor.getString(3));
    produto.setValorCusto(cursor.getString(4));
    produto.setEstoqueAtual(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
    return produto;
}

public ArrayList<Produto> getAllProdutos() {
    ArrayList<Produto> listaProdutos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABELA_PRODUTOS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Produto produto = cursorToProduto(cursor);
            listaProdutos.add(produto);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return listaProdutos;
}

}
```

E o erro que aparece no logCat:

```
11-15 20:44:23.340 3574-3591/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1 
E/EGL_emulation: tid 3591: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 
(EGL_BAD_MATCH)
11-15 20:44:32.923 3574-3591/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1 E/EGL_emulation: tid 3591: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
11-15 20:44:33.373 3574-3591/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1 E/EGL_emulation: tid 3591: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
11-15 20:44:35.791 3574-3574/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1 E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: produtos
11-15 20:44:35.796 3574-3574/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1, PID: 3574
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1/com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1.Produtos}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: produtos (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM produtos
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: produtos (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM produtos
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
    at com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1.DBHelper.getAllProdutos(DBHelper.java:131)
    at com.example.rodrigoconceicao.controleestoque2_1.Produtos.onCreate(Produtos.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que está bem claro seu problema, na linha do seu stacktrace:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: produtos
```

Em outras palavras, a tabela produtos não existe então o select nela retorna uma exception.

Answer (score 0):

o problema que você está errando na criação da tabela e das colunas. Você está colocando a variável  TABELA_PRODUTOS entre aspas. Tenha atenção para os nomes das tabelas e das colunas, é preciso desinstalar e reinstalar o app. Veja esse tutorial aqui.
https://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-crud-com-android-studio-e-sqlite/32815

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 1;
private static final String NOME_BANCO = "CONTROLE_DE_ESTOQUE";
private static final String TABELA_PRODUTOS = "produtos";
private static final String TABELA_USUARIOS = "usuarios";
private static final String ID = "_id";
private static final String DESCRICAO = "descricao";
private static final String CATEGORIA = "categoria";
private static final String UNIDADEMEDIDA = "unidadeMedida";
private static final String ESTOQUE_ATUAL = "estoqueAtual";
private static final String ESTOQUE_MINIMO = "estoqueMinimo";
private static final String VALOR_CUSTO = "valorCusto";
private static final String VALOR_VENDA = "valorVenda";
private static final String[] COLUNAS = {TABELA_PRODUTOS};

private static final String TABELA_FORNECEDORES = "fornecedores";
private static final String ID_FORNECEDOR = "_id";
private static final String RAZAO_SOCIAL = "razaoSocial";
private static final String CNPJ = "cnpj";
private static final String INSCRICAO_ESTADUAL = "inscricaoEstadual";
private static final String TELEFONE = "telefone";
private static final String ENDERECO = "endereco";
private static final String[] COLUNAS_FORNECEDOR = {TABELA_FORNECEDORES};


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO_BANCO);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String QUERY_USUARIO = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABELA_USUARIOS +"("+ID +" integer primary key autoincrement, nomeUsuario TEXT, senha TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(QUERY_USUARIO);
    Log.d("TAB","criou usuario");

    String QUERY_PRODUTO = "CREATE TABLE "+TABELA_PRODUTOS +"(" + ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, descricao TEXT, categoria TEXT," +
            " unidadeMedida TEXT, valorCusto TEXT, valorVenda TEXT, estoqueAtual TEXT, estoqueMinimo TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(QUERY_PRODUTO);
    Log.d("TAB","criou produto");

    String QUERY_FORNECEDOR = "CREATE TABLE " +TABELA_FORNECEDORES +"("+ID_FORNECEDOR +" integer primary key autoincrement, razaoSocial TEXT, cnpj TEXT," +
            " inscricaoEstadual TEXT, telefone TEXT, endereco TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(QUERY_FORNECEDOR);
    Log.d("TAB","criou fornecedor");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABELA_USUARIOS;");
    onCreate(db);

}

public long CriarUsuario(String nomeUsuario, String senha) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("nomeUsuario", nomeUsuario);
    cv.put("senha", senha);
    long result = db.insert(TABELA_USUARIOS, null, cv);
    return result;
}

public Boolean ValidarUsuario(String nomeUsuario, String senha) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABELA_USUARIOS +" WHERE nomeUsuario=? AND senha=?", new String[]{nomeUsuario, senha});
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public long CriarProduto(Produto produto) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DESCRICAO, produto.getDescricao());
    cv.put(CATEGORIA, produto.getCategoria());

    long result = db.insert(TABELA_PRODUTOS, null, cv);
    Log.d("TAB","inseriu "+produto.getDescricao());
    return result;
}

public Produto getProduto(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABELA_PRODUTOS, // a. tabela
            null, // b. colunas
            ID+"= ?", // c. colunas para comparar
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. parâmetros
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null); // h. limit
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Produto produto = cursorToProduto(cursor);
        return produto;
    }
}

private Produto cursorToProduto(Cursor cursor) {
    Produto produto = new Produto();
    produto.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
    produto.setDescricao(cursor.getString(1));
    produto.setCategoria(cursor.getString(2));
    return produto;
}

public ArrayList<Produto> getAllProdutos() {
    ArrayList<Produto> listaProdutos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABELA_PRODUTOS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Produto produto = cursorToProduto(cursor);
            listaProdutos.add(produto);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return listaProdutos;
}
```

}